# Exception: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; with Remote WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver

When I modified my code to run with RemoteWebDriver and ChromeDriver I am getting: Exception: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;

Code:

```
File file = new File("C:/WebDrivers/chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",file.getAbsolutePath());
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", Path_FileDownload);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.224.160:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
//driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The file exists on the PC that I am running it on.  When I switch to ChromeDriver instead of Remote WebDriver is works just fine.

Comment: Welcome to selenium hell. It appears that your path is not correct. Where is the chromedriver executable located on your system?

Comment: It is located at C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines

```
File file = new File("C:/WebDrivers/chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",file.getAbsolutePath());
```

work only when you use `ChromeDriver`.  I call this mode as `local` mode i.e., the JVM which runs the test case also spins off the browser.

When you use `RemoteWebDriver` you are working in a `remote` mode, because the JVM that spins off your test case, talks to another JVM (The selenium node) to spin off the browser.

When you are working with `RemoteWebDriver`, you are trying to connect to a different JVM running as the node through the hub.

For this use-case you would need to do one of the following in the machine wherein your node is running:

- Add `C:\WebDrivers` to your `PATH` variable. Make sure you confirm its added properly by opening up a new command prompt and running `echo %PATH%`. You should see `C:\WebDrivers` in the command output. **(or)**
- Start your node by adding `webdriver.chrome.driver` as a JVM argument. For e.g., something like this : `java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role node`

Answer (score 0):

You have two slashes at the start of your path:
`"C://WebDrivers" + "/chromedriver.exe"`

should be
`"C:/WebDrivers" + "/chromedriver.exe"`

Java file paths use '/' to separate directories and files, same as UNIX based systems.

Comment: I have to have the second slash to escape out the first slash.  Otherwise Java gives an error.

Comment: No you dont. You have to escape a '\' but not a '/'.

Comment: Still getting the same error.  I modified the file line to be: "C:/WebDrivers/chromedriver.exe", which loads when I put that into File Explorer.

Comment: Try printing the value of `System.getProperty(webdriver.chrome.driver)`. Might help us further.

Comment: I added System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver")); to the code, right after System.setProperty.  And it gives me: C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe

Comment: Try using "C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe" instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary("Chrome_Binary/chrome.exe");
    options.addArguments("--start-fullscreen");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Drivers/Chrome/chromedriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```